# Почему .loc не может отфильтровать таблицу по индексам?

Tags: python, pandas

Вот часть кода:

```
y_train = y_train.loc[idxs]
```

Вот что из себя представляет idxs вместе с ошибкой:

```
KeyError: '[105, 5, 240, 285, 50, 190, 279, 22, 82, 33, 194, 94, 259, 191, 64, 58, 30, 119, 218, 249, 109, 43, 181, 247, 75, 20, 32, 52, 176, 203, 165, 168, 44, 167, 232, 258, 242, 145, 265, 23, 40, 139, 136, 137, 164, 38, 228, 174, 55, 152, 201, 251, 138, 185, 98, 123, 234, 6, 244] not in index'
```

Я понимаю, что написано в ошибке, но проблема в том, что этот же код работал еще час назад, а сейчас уже нет(звучит странно, но так и есть))

Comment: потому что по индексам локализует метод `.iloc` а не `.loc`.

Comment: Пробовал уже, выдает это: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: Ну смотрите, мы можем и дальше гадать на кофейной гуще, пока ваш вопрос не закроют за нарушения правил сайта, либо вы все-таки выложите воспроизводимый пример исходных данных и желаемый результат.

Comment: @strawdog А причем тут воспроизводимый пример? Применительно к этой задаче я хочу добиться одного - достать из датасета строки с индексами, которые хранятся в списке idxs - это можно реализовать на любом сгенерированном датасете.

Comment: @Lorandius, откройте документацию по loc/iloc - там есть пример "любого сгенерированного датасета", на котором все работает  Вам это сильно поможет??